# How to make a html/css 3 row layout where the middle row fits the remaining content and does not expand the parent

Tags: html, css

I need to create a 3 row layout that will sit inside the middle column of a flex 3 column layout.

The layout should fill this middle column (100%,100%) and should contain:

- Top row: can be empty or have content. It's height should be auto, and should expand to its content.
- Bottom row: same as top row.
- Center row: should fill the rest of the vertical space, and should not make the whole structure expand beyond what it was initially

Here is a graphical description:

[image]

I first tried with a table, however this had a problem that when the center cell expanded it would expand the whole table and the table would not respect the height.

Next I tried with display:flex and had basically the same problem, when the center div would get a lot of content the inner content would not scroll but the div would expand beyond the available space.

I am struggling to make this work as expected...

This is one of my failed attempts:

https://jsfiddle.net/zm12bgxq/

```js
$("#fillme").click(() => {
  $("#row-center").empty();
  let pre = $("<pre>");
  pre.css({
    "white-space": "pre-wrap",
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "overflow-x": "auto"
  })
  $("#row-center").append(pre);
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pre.append("<span>Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text<br></span>")
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#body {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mainWin,
#content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#mainWin {
  flex: 1;
}

#menuBar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

#content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#column-left {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: green;
}

#column-right {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: green;
}

#column-center {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#center-content {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#center-content table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#center-content tr {
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#center-content td {
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#row-top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row-center {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: white;
}

#row-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="menuBar">
    <ul>
      <li>Somemenu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mainWin">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="column-left">
        Left
      </div>
      <div id="column-center">
        <div id="center-content">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-top">Top</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-center">
                  <button id="fillme">
                Fill me
              </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-bottom">
                  <div id="cmdCont">
                    <textarea autofocus="" rows="1" style="width:100%;height: 20px;"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="column-right">
        Right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here it looks ok until you press the button and the white box expands the table... even tough the table has fixed size (50% of parent). The pre gets a scrollbar but since it is expanded to maximum it means nothing...

What should happen is that the white box remains the same size and the pre fills it and the pre gets a scrollbar that is actually scrolling.

Another concern is having "white-space: pre" on the pre, which should not expand the white box neither horizontally. it should be clipped or if i put overflow-x: scroll then it should be viewable by scrolling the pre.

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet, but your div code is not the same as the table code in the fiddle

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong link, i updated the question now

Comment: But make SNIPPETS so we do not have to leave SO to look

Comment: There is one now, but I did't know how to do it. Will try next time. Sorry.

Comment: Just click the `[<>]` snippet editor button

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* avoid using `<table>` for laying out your page (unless it's for an actual table). Save yourself the future hassle and use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) instead.

A 3 column layout similar to how you described is as simple as:

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.middle {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

**EDIT:** I couldn't easily tell which code in your fiddle was a requirement, and which was just part of the debugging process. So here's a replica I *rebuilt* using CSS grid that solves your issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/mwsj94qx/

Comment: It seems to me that the 1fr expands further than the height of it's parent when the content inside is tall. At least tested in firefox. Maybe I am missing something. If you can make a fiddle of it working by starting from my fiddle in the question it would be perfect.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new fiddle. A lot of html/css has been stripped out but I hope you can still find it useful. :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort eddie, unfortunately I already knew that giving the middle cell overflow fixes the problem. However this does not work for me because the inner PRE that I am injecting is a component I don't have access to and manages it's own scroll. So the PRE must scroll and not the div like in your example.

Comment: Interesting, are you able to give the inner `<pre>` a `height: 100%`? Doing so will constrict it and allow it to scroll. (I've changed the same fiddle with a new one with an example)

Answer (score 0):

Cant you simply add a class like so...

```
pre {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}
```

```js
$("#fillme").click(() => {
  $("#row-center").empty();
  let pre = $("<pre>");
  pre.css({
    "white-space": "pre-wrap",
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "overflow-x": "auto"
  })
  $("#row-center").append(pre);
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pre.append("<span>Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text, Some long text<br></span>")
  }
})
```

```css
pre {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}
  
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#body {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mainWin,
#content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#mainWin {
  flex: 1;
}

#menuBar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

#content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#column-left {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: green;
}

#column-right {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: green;
}

#column-center {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#center-content {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#center-content table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#center-content tr {
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#center-content td {
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#row-top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row-center {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: white;
}

#row-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="menuBar">
    <ul>
      <li>Somemenu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mainWin">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="column-left">
        Left
      </div>
      <div id="column-center">
        <div id="center-content">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-top">Top</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-center">
                  <button id="fillme">
                Fill me
              </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="row-bottom">
                  <div id="cmdCont">
                    <textarea autofocus="" rows="1" style="width:100%;height: 20px;"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="column-right">
        Right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Il works in chrome, in firefox the table expands vertically beyond the percentage of the relative parent set in its style.

Comment: Maybe tables is a no-go, but I have similar problems settings a layout with divs.

Comment: Just set position: absolute and top: 0; Check update.